# Question regarding a method of finding the limit of a composition of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

**Motivation:**
Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \bigg(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\bigg)^x ~.$$

To find this limit, we learned from elementary calculus that we can change the variable $x$ to $x^2$ something else to get rid of the root sign, for instance, $\lim_{x\to \infty} \bigg(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\bigg)^x=\lim_{t\to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{t})^{t^2}=\lim_{t\to \infty} \bigg[\bigg(1+\frac{1}{t}\bigg)^t\bigg]^t=\lim_{t\to \infty}e^t=\infty$.

Indeed, such transformations of variables in computing limits occur frequently. For instance, to compute $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{2}{3n})^{4n}$, we would change $n$ to $\frac{3n}{2}$ and use our knowledge of the euler number.

In order to understand this process of changing variable analytically, I interpreted the process as a composition of functions. For example, $\bigg(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt x} \bigg)^{x}=g \circ f(x)$, where $f(x)=\sqrt x$ and $g(x) = \bigg(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\bigg)^x$.

Now I found from a problem on a text on introduction to analysis that if $\lim_{x\to \infty}g=L$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}f=\infty$, then $\lim_{x\to \infty}f\circ g=L$. So combining the above results we get the limit. I'm wondering whether this is the correct analytic interpretation of such variable transformations used in computing limits.

**Question:** I naturally tried to extend the idea of this theorem.

**Conjecture** If $\lim_{x\to b}g=L$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f=b$, then $\lim_{x\to a}g\circ f=L$.

I first thought this is correct because the proof is so straightforward.

Since $\lim_{x\to b}g=L$, given any $\epsilon \gt 0$, there is some $\delta \gt 0$ such that if $0\lt |x-b| \lt \delta$ then $|g(x)-L|\lt \epsilon$. And since $\lim_{x\to a}f=b$, we can find a $\delta' \gt 0$ such that if $0\lt |x-a| \lt \delta'$ then $|f(x)-b|\lt \delta$. Combining these two, given $\epsilon \gt 0$, we've found some $\delta' \gt 0$ such that if $0\lt |x-a| \lt \delta'$ then $|g(f(x))-L|\lt \epsilon$.

However, I just found from a text that this is false, in fact it is true if $g$ is continuous at $L$. Here is a counterexample given in the text for the case in which $g$ is not continuous. $f(x)=1+x\sin\frac{\pi}{x}$ for $x\neq 0$, $g(x)=4$ for $x\neq1$ and $g(1)=-4$. Then for $x_n=\frac{2}{n}$, $f(x_n)=1$ for even $n$ and $f(x_n)\neq 1$ for odd $n$ so $g \circ f(x_n)=-4$ for even $n$ and $4$ for odd $n$, yielding a contradiction.

To figure out what is wrong with my proof, I realized that if$|f(x)-b|=0$, then the proof doesn't guarantee the result since we only assume that if $0\lt |x-b| \lt \delta$ then $|g(x)-L|\lt \epsilon$. And this is exactly the reasoning behind the counterexample.

So this prompted me to another observation. If $\lim_{x\to a}f=b$ but $f(x)\neq b$ in some neighborhood of $a$, then the conjecture should be true since we are guaranteed that we can find a $\delta' \gt 0$ such that if $0\lt |x-a| \lt \delta'$ then $0\lt |f(x)-b|\lt \delta$. Moreover, if this is true, then we can always find a one-to-one function to make variable transformations when computing limits. Is this conjecture true?

Finally, I'm curious about the relationship between the limit of a sequence and the limit at infinity of a function. Often times in computing the limit of a sequence, I would see in texts that the author would interpret the sequence as a function of real domain and the limit at infinity of a function, like in the case of computing $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{2}{3n})^{4n}$. I think this is due to the fact that if $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=L$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(n)=L$, where $n$ is a natural number, i.e. $f(n)$ is a sequence. This seems obvious from definition of limits but is this true? On the other, I have a hunch that the converse direction is not true, but I'm having trouble finding a counterexample.

I would appreciate if anyone can clear up the questions I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is a typo in your conjecture: it should br $g\circ f$ instead of $f\circ g$.

**First question**. Yes, if $f(x)\ne b$ in a neighborhood of $a$ then the conjecture is true. But the last part about the one to one function does not necessarely hold. Consider for instance $f(x)=x(2+\sin(1/x))$. $f(x)=0$ only if $x=0$, but $f$ is not one to one on any neighborhood of $0$.

**Second question**. If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ and $x_n$ is such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\infty$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=L$. Conversely, if for **every** sequence $x_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\infty$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=L$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$. It is easy to find examples such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=L$ for some sequence, but $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ does not exist; here is an example: $f(x)=\sin(\pi\,x)$, $x_n=n$.

Comment: Thanks. I just mentioned the last part that the conjecture is true if $f$ is one to one because often times we use one to one transformations. For instance to find $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin 5x}{x}$, we'd change this to $5*\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin 5x}{5x}=5*\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}$, and I'm assuming that in such instances we're implicitly using the conjecture, where $f=5x$ in this case clearly works since it's one to one. Actually, I know that in such cases we need not resort to this conjecture because $\sin(x)/x$ is continuous, but I was just trying to find a more general way.